# how can i upload file by using xpath in cypress

Tags: cypress

How can upload file by using xpath in cypress?

Am getting as mentioned below error...

```html
const xpath = require('cypress-xpath')
describe('File upload Demo', () => {
  
  Cypress.Commands.add('uploadFile', { prevSubject: 'element' }, (subject, fileName) => {
      console.log('subject', subject)
      return cy.fixture(fileName, 'base64')
        .then(Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob)
        .then(blob => {
          console.log('blob', blob)
          const el = subject[0]
          if (el != null) {
            const testFile = new File([blob], fileName)
            const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
            dataTransfer.items.add(testFile)
            el.files = dataTransfer.files
          }
          return subject          
        })
      }
    )
  
    it('upload file test', () => {

      cy.visit('https://tus.io/demo.html')

      cy.xpath('//input[@type="file"]').upload('401k_deferral.xlsx')
      
      cy.get('[class="button primary"]').should('have.class', 'button primary')
    })
  
  })
```

TypeError: cy.xpath(...).upload is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom command you have added is called `uploadFile` but you are trying to call `upload`.

Try this:

```
      cy.xpath('//input[@type="file"]').uploadFile('401k_deferral.xlsx')
```